# How to use Manipulate to mimic a oscillation along the Y-axis

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

I'm trying to figure out how to make a ball oscillate straight up and down using an equation such as Cos[Pi*x*3]. I want to use the Manipulate feature to act as  the x value, but I don't want the x value represented graphically at all. How can I essentially create a one dimensional plot using Mathematica?

Comment: At first I tried to use only the plot function (minus the dot), but when i couldn't alter the x coordinates, I figured I'd have to use the graphics feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Animate[Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, Cos[3 Pi p]}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Axes -> True], {p, 0, 1}]
```

[image]